# How do we get more activity in the chat room? Is it worth the bother while chat is still in beta?

Tags: discussion, chat, recent-activity

The [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22/show-me-the-money) was recently frozen due to inactivity.  I'll try to chat in there to prevent it from happeneing again, even if I end up talking to myself.  However, I was wondering how could we get people in there?  Is it worth fussing over it while chat is in beta and we're striving to get more activity on the site itself?

While we typically think of chat as an interactive/real-time activity, the transcript & notification features of SE chat make it a suitable candidate for less real-time activity.  That said, with the way feeds are displayed, it is easy for things to get lost in the "noise."

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there shouldn't be a question feed in the room.    If it stays empty, ok, if it has conversation, ok.

Answer (score 0):

Does chat have a use-case for Money?  For RPG and Gaming there's a great desire to discuss things, and generally talk about the topic.  Is there the same need for Money.

I guess the question is: **Are we trying to solve a problem that isn't there?**